# How to smooth image load using Piccaso image loading library in android?

Tags: android, image, listview, load, android-imageview

Currently I'm using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) this library as image loading. I'm trying to load 1000 image in listview using this library but it takes time and also stuck my app.what I can do for smooth user experience ? I'm using following code in adapter for image load.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(path + list.get(position)))
                     .centerCrop()
                     .resize(150, 150)
                     .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                     .into(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Loading 1000 images in to a ListView is going to cause a lot of memory issues and will slow down your device.

I've actually had a problem like this before and I found the solution to be to use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`.

A `RecyclerView`does just that, instead of creating and inflating a new view every time, it recycles the view that just disappeared and changes the content of it so it can be added to the bottom of the `RecyclerView`.

Have a look at this sample code below:

Firstly Add `RecyclerView` to `Gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
```

Add `RecyclerView` to xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
```

Initialise `RecyclerView` in `Activity`

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Then create your `RecyclerView` adapter

```
public class EventListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
public ArrayList<EventObject> eventList;
private String category;

/**
 * Viewholder class for view reuse
 */
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private PEWImageView img_main;
    private RelativeLayout layoutItem;
    private TextView txt_event_name;
    private TextView txt_event_details;
    private TextView txt_going_to;
    private View gradient_view;

    /**
     * Viewholder contructor where all assignments take place so this is only done once
     * @param itemView
     * @param context
     */
    public ViewHolder(View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView);
        img_main = (PEWImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_main);
        txt_event_details = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_details);
        txt_event_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_name);
        txt_going_to = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_going_to);
        gradient_view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gradient_view);
        layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_event_item);

        txt_event_name.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansBold(context));
        txt_event_details.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansLight(context));
        txt_going_to.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansLight(context));
    }

    /**
     * Sets up UI for each item
     * @param context
     * @param eventObject
     * @param category
     * @throws JSONException
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    public void bindView(final Context context, final EventObject eventObject, String category) throws JSONException, ParseException {

        /**
         * Handles special characters
         */
        txt_event_name.setText(Html.fromHtml(eventObject.getEventName()));

        /**
         * Checks if venue name contains the name of the town
         */
        if (eventObject.getVenueName().contains(eventObject.getTown())) {
            txt_event_details.setText(eventObject.getVenueName() + ", " + getFormattedDate(eventObject.getEventDate()));
        } else {
            txt_event_details.setText(eventObject.getVenueName() + ", " + eventObject.getTown() + ", " + getFormattedDate(eventObject.getEventDate()));
        }

        /**
         * Checks if event should have yellow box above
         */
        try {
            if (eventObject.getFeeFreeStatus() == 1) {
                txt_going_to.setVisibility(category.equalsIgnoreCase("no fees") ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                txt_going_to.setText("Fee free tickets available");
            } else {
                txt_going_to.setVisibility(Integer.parseInt(eventObject.getGoingToCount()) >= 200 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                txt_going_to.setText("Popular event: " + eventObject.getGoingToCount() + " going");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            txt_going_to.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        /**
         * Sets colour gradient over image
         */
        if (eventObject.getHeaderHex() != null && !eventObject.getHeaderHex().equals("")) {
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{Color.TRANSPARENT, alterColor(Color.parseColor(eventObject.getHeaderHex()), 0.2f)});
            gd.setCornerRadius(0f);

            gradient_view.setBackground(gd);
        }

        layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((HomeActivity) context).setEventProfileFrag(eventObject.getFullJsonObject(), null);
            }
        });

        /**
         * Loads image in to layout item
         */
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(eventObject.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_skiddle_placeholder)
                .noFade()
                .into(img_main);

    }

    /**
     * Formats the date returned from the API
     * @param dateString
     * @return
     * @throws ParseException
     */
    private String getFormattedDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.UK);
        Date newDate = format.parse(dateString);
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM", Locale.UK);
        String date = format.format(newDate);
        return date;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the view holder
 * @param parent
 * @param viewType
 * @return
 */
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_event_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView, parent.getContext());
}

/**
 * Binds the viewholder to the recyclerview
 * @param holder
 * @param position
 */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        holder.bindView(context, eventList.get(position), this.category);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the item id
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of items in the adapter
 * @return
 */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return eventList.size();
}

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param context
 * @param eventList
 * @param category
 */
public EventListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EventObject> eventList, String category) {
    this.context = context;
    this.eventList = eventList;
    this.category = category;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

/**
 * Method to add items to the adapter (for pagination)
 * @param eventList
 */
public void addItems(ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
    this.eventList.addAll(eventList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Method to darken the head hex colour for the gradient overlay
 * @param color
 * @param factor
 * @return
 */
public static int alterColor(int color, float factor) {
    int a = (color & (0xFF << 24)) >> 24;
    int r = (int) (((color & (0xFF << 16)) >> 16) * factor);
    int g = (int) (((color & (0xFF << 8)) >> 8) * factor);
    int b = (int) ((color & 0xFF) * factor);
    return Color.argb(a, r, g, b);
}
}
```

Then just set the adapter to the `RecyclerView` in the activity.

You can change this adapter for how you need it but the main concept is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

> Glide :- https://github.com/bumptech/glide

replace Picasso

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem when I was trying to develop gallery app and loading many images.

For solution I've changed picasso version as below and it worked fine enough.

add following in your app level build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
}

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.3-SNAPSHOT'
```